# Laravel- Jquery not work

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.6

I use `Laravel 5.6`. I have a `master.blade.php` file. I added the following script to this file for using `jquery`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have created `app1.js` file and inserted my jquery code in it I also imported this file in `master.blade.php`. However, the jquery code not work at all. I thought this may the case of jquery confusion with `app.js`. For this reason, I have also deleted the content of `app.js`, but it didn't work again. I have deleted the `app1.js` file and inserted my jquery code in `app.js` but it didn't work. What shall I do to use `jquery` in `Laravel 5.6`?

Comment: What errors are you getting in your console log? (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome > console)

Comment: what errors are you getting? Is app1.js called after the jquery call on the master?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and navigate to the console tab and see what errors are being produced - also as a note - it's preferred to host js/css on your server for reliability purposes (e.g., if code.jquery.com went down, none of your site jQuery would work)

Comment: @LuísAlmeida Thanks. I have called app.js before the jquery call. Now it works for "console.log('It works!');" but for jquery statements it still not works.

Comment: @Martin it doesn't have any error.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it doesn't have any error.

Comment: What code of jquery are you using?

Comment: Could you post your jQuery code that is supposedly not working? As well as the elements (html) it's supposed to interact with?